# Setup Angular CLI on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, angular-cli

I'm working on a xubuntu 16.04 LTS version and I'm trying to install the Angular cli on my machine. I have already tried to remove, clean the npm cache, then reinstall, but that doesn't work. When I write `npm install -g @angular/cli` in the console, I got the following errors:

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-78-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/papamilo/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running it as root like this:

```
$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```